# How to parse and format content of HTML file element using JSoup?

Tags: java, html, parsing, html-table, jsoup

I was asked to output the code that was given, in the specific (correct and identical) format in the table, by using any means (however I have chosen the JSoup parser, as I think it is the best solution). I have done some research and watched tutorials in order to understand how things work, but got stuck.

I have already tried looking through the StackOverflow and found a similar question, however, I am not able to apply the previous solution to my task.

I have a table with three rows and eight columns in which each individual cell has to be formatted in a specific way (some of the formatting is similar, uppercase to the whole text, date format). I was thinking of extracting each of them and then try to use a regex, however, I have only managed to extract each individual row.

Below is the aforementioned table which I am trying to parse.

the code:

```
    ArrayList<String> tableContent = new ArrayList<>();
    File input = new File("[..]task_A1.html");
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");


    Element table = doc.select("table").get(0);
    Elements rows = table.select("tr");


    for(int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++){
        Element row = rows.get(i);
        Elements cols = row.select("th");

        tableContent.add(cols.text());
    }

}
```

```
<table>
<tr class="primera odd">
<th class="titulo ini" scope="row">2017/10/10</th>
<th class="titulo" scope="col">Demand (b.c)</th>
<th class="titulo" scope="col">Generation(1,234.56)</th>
<th class="titulo" scope="col">Motores diesel</th>
<th class="titulo" scope="col">Turbina de gas</th>
<th class="titulo" scope="col">Fuel + Gas</th>
<th class="titulo" scope="col">Ciclo combinado (3)</th>
<th class="titulo" scope="col">GeneraciÃ³n auxiliar (4)</th>
</tr>

<tr class="primera odd">
<th class="titulo ini" scope="row">10102017T0000</th>
<th class="titulo" scope="col">Demand (B.C)</th>
<th class="titulo" scope="col">GENERATION(1234.56)</th>
<th class="titulo" scope="col">Motores diesel</th>
<th class="titulo" scope="col">Turbina%de%gas</th>
<th class="titulo" scope="col">Fuel y Gas(3)</th>
<th class="titulo" scope="col">Ciclo combinado</th>
<th class="titulo" scope="col">GeneraciÃ³n auxiliar (4)</th>
</tr>

<tr class="primera odd">
<th class="titulo ini" scope="row">10-10-2017</th>
<th class="titulo" scope="col">Demand (b.c)</th>
<th class="titulo" scope="col">Generation(1234,56)</th>
<th class="titulo" scope="col">Motores diesel</th>
<th class="titulo" scope="col">Turbina de gas</th>
<th class="titulo" scope="col">Fuel y Gas</th>
<th class="titulo" scope="col">Ciclo combinado</th>
<th class="titulo" scope="col">GeneraciÃ³n.auxiliar</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Table:

2017/10/10  Demand (b.c)    Generation(1,234.56)    Motores diesel  Turbina de gas  Fuel + Gas  Ciclo combinado (3) GeneraciÃ³n auxiliar (4)

10102017T0000   Demand (B.C)    GENERATION(1234.56) Motores diesel  Turbina%de%gas  Fuel y Gas(3)   Ciclo combinado GeneraciÃ³n auxiliar (4)

10-10-2017  Demand (b.c)    Generation(1234,56) Motores diesel  Turbina de gas  Fuel y Gas  Ciclo combinado GeneraciÃ³n.auxiliar

Correct table output:

10-10-2017    DEMAND (B.C)    GENERATION(1234,56)    MOTORES DIESEL    TURBINA DE GAS    FUEL Y GAS    CICLO COMBINADO    GENERACIóN.AUXILIAR

10-10-2017    DEMAND (B.C)    GENERATION(1234,56)    MOTORES DIESEL    TURBINA DE GAS    FUEL Y GAS    CICLO COMBINADO    GENERACIóN.AUXILIAR

10-10-2017    DEMAND (B.C)    GENERATION(1234,56)    MOTORES DIESEL    TURBINA DE GAS    FUEL Y GAS    CICLO COMBINADO    GENERACIóN.AUXILIAR

The question is, how to extract / format / parse the given table, in order to get all the cells identically and correctly formatted? Is it even possible to fulfill this task by using JSoup or is there a better solution to this problem?

I will appreciate any suggestions.